# How to completely replace python 3 with python 2 in arch linux

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, environment-variables, archlinux

I want to completely replace python 3 with python 2 in arch linux. I have already read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python but it only provides a temporary fix. I need to ensure that when I call

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

My program is using python 2 instead of python 3.

Comment: you should really change your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python2` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Arch, `/usr/bin/python` is actually a symlink to python3.  Assuming you've already installed python2, as root, change the symlink to point to python2:

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -l python
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7  5 sept. 07:04 python -> python3
ln -sf python2 python
ls -l python
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 11 19:28 python -> python2
```

If you're using the `python2-virtualenv` package, then do the same for `/usr/bin/virtualenv`:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -sf virtualenv2 virtualenv
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this to the Arch wiki.

Comment: Just want to add that this seems really dangerous. Doesn't this just mean that all scripts using python on the base install (since python3 is default) will just start breaking?

Comment: @ToddMorrison Totally possible, if they rely on something deprecated by v3!  But it's what the OP asked for and Arch is all about ripping off that band-aid and python 2.7 is the end of the road for v2.

Comment: Just a note that this may not be as permanent as it seems - after an update to python3 I found that the symlink /usr/bin/python was restored to link to python3

Answer (score 10):

Changing the default symlink is a bad idea, and it gets recreated on python3 updates. Instead, create a local `python` override:

`sudoedit /usr/local/bin/python`

Paste this inside and save the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec python2 "$@"
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Even simpler: symlink it. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python`. Do the same for `pip` and `virtualenv`.